# we need to pick out the cases where $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is analytic but not neccessarily constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

we need to pick out the cases where $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is analytic but not neccessarily constant.

$1.$$ \Im(f'(z))>0$ for all $z$

$2.$ $f(n)=3\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$

$3$ $f'(0)=0$ and $|f'(z)|\le 3\forall z$

My attempt:

$1$. take $f(z)=\sin z+ 2iz$

$2$. take $f(z)=3\sin (\frac{\pi z}{2})$

$3$. $f'$ must be constant as  $f'$ is bounded analytic,hence constant so $f(z)=cz$, for some complex constant $c$.

Please  tell me whether  I am right.

Comment: I don't think $1$. works. At $z = 2 + 2i$ it looks like $\mathfrak{Im}(f'(z)) < 0$..

Comment: In 3 do you mean $f(0)=0$?

Comment: For 1) you can take $f(z) = iz$.

Comment: @Urgent (2) $f(3)=-3$ am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Simply let $f'(z)=i$ (constant). Then $f(z)=iz$ is a solution.
2. is ok the way you do it
3. You missed a little point: $f'(0)=0$ and $f'$ constant implies $f'(z)=0$ and $f$ constant. If the first condition were $f(0)=0$, then $f(z)=cz$ would be fine.

Comment: 1. In such a case, $f'$ is necessarily constant, so an answer similar to Hagen's is all that is possible. 2. Although something similar will work, what is written in the question is incorrect.  E.g., try $n=0$.